# Установка библиотек yt-dlp и ffmpeg через nuget

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

Я сейчас делаю приложение на c# и использую такие библиотеки как "yt-dlp" и "ffmpeg". Подскажите можно ли установить их как dll через nuget? Просто я не нашел. Устанавливать с помощью "Chocolatey" хороший вариант, но немного неудобно в плане установки самой программы.

Comment: Неуправляемые библиотеки подключаются через DllImport в коде. Саму dll можно просто скопировать.

Comment: ffmpeg и YoutubeDLSharp есть в nuget.